# Logic for overloading bitshift operators in Python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading

I have a Python a python class and I overloading the `>>` operator so that I can create a quasi 'connection' interface. An example in ideal practice is something like this.

```py
from module import myclass
a = myclass()
b = myclass()
c = myclass()

a >> b >> c
```

My overloading function is very simple so far:

```py
def __rshift__(self, right):
    self.chain[right] = None
    return self
```

When `a` and `b` and `c` are connected like so, the idea is that `a` will store `b` in a hash table, `b` will store `c` in a hash table.

The problem is that in practice, `a` also receives `c` and stores it in the hash table. I only want `a` to know about `b` so that later on I can traverse from `a` to `b` to `c` by iterating over the keys of `self.chain`.

I can get around this by restructuring the code like so:

```py
a >> b
b >> c
```

So what am I missing here? How can I either change my implementation so that you can specify the whole series of connections on line, or is this never going to be possible?

Comment: If you want `>> c` to be performed on `b` instead of `a`, then it sounds like you want `a << b` to return `b` instead of `a`. So make your `__rshift__` method return `right` instead of `self`. But better advice would probably be "don't do this at all; it's confusing".

Comment: Thanks but my use case is fairly niche and I'm fine with it being confusing in a more general sense in favour of having an idiomatic feel to it.

Answer (score 3):

After setting the hash, you could return `right` so the chaining behavior would then apply to the next class object.

```
def __rshift__(self, right):
    self.chain[right] = None
    return right
```

Then for example after `a >> b >> c`

```
>>> a
<__main__.myclass object at 0x000002128A755388>
>>> b
<__main__.myclass object at 0x000002128A70BBC8>
>>> c
<__main__.myclass object at 0x000002128A74BC48>

>>> a.chain
{<__main__.myclass object at 0x000002128A70BBC8>: None}  # stored b
>>> b.chain
{<__main__.myclass object at 0x000002128A74BC48>: None}  # stored c
>>> c.chain
{}
```

Now `a` has an entry for `b`, `b` has an entry for `c`, and `c` is empty

Comment: Ugh, this is so perfectly simple. It was kind of staring me in the face but I didn't make the leap that I needed to pass the right operand rather than the self. Thanks Cory.